# Export Outlook Emails from a Public folder to put inside Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to export emails from a public folder into an Excel sheet but I encountered an error somewhere in my code:

```
Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace(“MAPI”)
Set Folder = Session.Folders(strMailboxName)
```

How do I solve it?

In addition, is there a way to extract the email address of the sender to be included inside “email_Sender” too?

Thank you.

```
Sub GetFromOutlook()

Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim OutlookMail As Variant
Dim strMailboxName As String
Dim i As Integer

strMailboxName = “DCASecure”

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace(“MAPI”)
Set Folder = Session.Folders(strMailboxName)
Set Folder = Folder.Folders(“Inbox”)

i = 1

For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range(“From_date”).Value Then
Range(“email_Subject”).Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
Range(“email_Subject”).Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
Range(“email_Subject”).Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
Range(“email_Date”).Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
Range(“email_Date”).Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
Range(“email_Date”).Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
Range(“email_Sender”).Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.SenderName
Range(“email_Sender”).Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
Range(“email_Sender”).Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop

i = i + 1
End If
Next OutlookMail

Set Folder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: `but I encountered an error somewhere in my code:` What error and where?

Comment: Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application

Comment: That answers the "Where" part. What about "What"? :)

Comment: It cannot run the code

Comment: What Error do you get? What does the error say?

Comment: I have a feeling that you have not set a reference to the MS Outlook and maybe getting the error `Compile Error: User defined type not define`? If that is the case then you may want to read [Automating Outlook from a Visual Basic Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/automating-outlook-from-a-visual-basic-application)

Comment: Once that is sorted, you **may** get an error on `strMailboxName = “DCASecure”` If you copied the code from some website and put it in your VBA and then directly copied it here then you **may** have incorrect double quotes. Change `“` and `”` to `"` everywhere

Comment: Sorry, I cannot remember the error code since the outlook app is only installed in my work computer (i don't have it with me now), I'll get back to you on Monday (3 Feb). Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I have followed you steps above but I got an error Run-time error '-2147221233 (8004010F)': The attempted operation failed. An object could not be found. Debug: Set Folder = Session.Folders(strMailboxName)

Comment: Just above the comments, click on "edit" to add the error and the applicable line.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you've added **reference to "Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library"**. If not, follow these steps:

1. Press Alt + F11 (to open developer view)
2. Click on "Tools" and then "References" (Or Alt -> T -> R)
3. Make sure you have checked the "Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library"

Comment: Hi, I have added it but I got an error Run-time error '-2147221233 (8004010F)': The attempted operation failed. An object could not be found  ''' Set Folder = Session.Folders(strMailboxName) '''

Comment: That's a good progress. It means that now it works, but your folder structure may be different. Are you sure you have "DCASecure" folder in your inbox? Maybe you have multiple accounts connected?

Also, try to change

Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace(“MAPI”)
Set Folder = Session.Folders(strMailboxName)
Set Folder = Folder.Folders(“Inbox”)

=========== TO ===========

Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace(“MAPI”)
Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.Folders(strMailboxName)

Comment: I managed to run the code! Turns out I have to change DCASecure to DCA Secure instead. Is there a way to extract the email address of the sender to be included inside the code “email_Sender” too?